# VGG16 doesn't increase accuracy in TFF

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tf.keras, tensorflow-federated

I am trying to do transfer learning on my own dataset. I managed to do transfer learning with resnet and I got decent accuracy. But when I try VGG16 my accuracy stays the same all the time and loss is changing. I preprocessed my images with  tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input. Also, I tried to do transfer learning in a centralized manner and it works fine.

```
if base_model == "VGG16":
            base_model = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(
                include_top=False,
                weights="imagenet",
                input_tensor=tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(input_shape, input_shape, 3)),
                pooling=None,
            )

 base_model.trainable = False

        inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(input_shape, input_shape, 3))
        x = base_model(inputs, training=False)

        x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

        outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(x)
        model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

        return model

    def create_FL_model():

        """create_FL_model_test _summary_

        Returns:
            tff.learning.Model: _description_
        """
        keras_model = load_model(name, base_model)
        return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
            keras_model,
            input_spec=input_spec.element_spec,
            loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
            metrics=[
                tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(),
            ],
        )

    # check again
    if fed_alg == "FedAvg":

        transfer_learning_iterative_process = (
            tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
                create_FL_model,
                client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.02),
                server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.0),
            )
        )


    keras_model = load_model(name, base_model)

    state_transfer = transfer_learning_iterative_process.initialize()

    state = tff.learning.state_with_new_model_weights(
        state_transfer,
        trainable_weights=[v.numpy() for v in keras_model.trainable_weights],
        non_trainable_weights=[v.numpy() for v in keras_model.non_trainable_weights],
    )
```

Training round:

```
   for epoch in range(num_epochs):

    client_data_train, client_data_valid = client_data.train_test_client_split(
        client_data, num_test_clients=1, seed=12345
    )
    fed_valid_data = preprocess(
        client_data_valid.create_tf_dataset_for_client(
            client_data_valid.client_ids[0]
        )
    )

    random_clients_ids = random.sample(client_data_train.client_ids, k=2)

    federated_train_data = make_federated_data(
        client_data_train, random_clients_ids
    )
    state, metrics = transfer_learning_iterative_process.next(
        state, federated_train_data
    )
```